# Build a custom Firefox distribution including a JRE installation.and Java Plugin

Tags: java, firefox, applet, mozilla, custom-build

I need to generate a customized version of Firefox, and it will need to have the java plugin pre-enabled.
I would like to embed the installation of JRE with my firefox package customized in a subdirectory. For example:

```
$Firefox_path/browser/
$Firefox_path/defaults/
$Firefox_path/distribution/
$Firefox_path/my_JRE/
...
```

However, the Java Plugin search the JRE installed in the Windows registry. (HKLM\Software\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin,version=xx.xx.xx)

It is possible to force the java plugin use my JRE distributed with custom Firefox?

```
$Firefox_path/my_JRE/
```

Tks for your attention!
o/

Comment: You'd be much better served by spending the time to convert your applet to an application and getting people to install it rather than your customized Firefox. Less work, fewer hassles, essentially the same result. (It happens a client has us doing this right now...)

Comment: Tks for comment, @T.J.Crowder! But unfortunately our application is very large, it is a complete ERP and we are migrating the technology concurrently. That will still consume plenty of time. = ]